# Why wrap functions?

Tags: linux, kernel, c

Why does the Linux kernel sometimes implement multiple versions of a function with very similar names that just wrap another function? For example, [here](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/time/clocksource.c#L645):

```c
static void clocksource_select(void)
{
    __clocksource_select(false);
}

static void clocksource_select_fallback(void)
{
    __clocksource_select(true);
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you want to pass this functions to some other functions expecting a specific signature. Or store in some function table expecting a specific signature. Or to comply with specific interface. Or just for convenience/readability. Can be some other reasons too.

Comment: Have you not noticed in your example that the two wrapper functions pass the wrapped function different values?

Comment: "very similar names that just wrap another function"  that is not truly done here.  `clocksource_select()` and `__clocksource_select()` have different function signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you gave is not a very good example, because it has nothing to do with the Linux kernel. This is just basic software engineering.

When you have two functions that need to have very close functionality, there are several paths you can take.

1. You can implement the function twice. We don't like to do that, as it creates code duplication. It also means that if you need to change something in the common area of the code, you need to remember to change it at two places.
2. You can split the common code into its own function, and call that function from each of the functions. That is the best solution *if it is possible*. The problem is that it is not always possible. It might not be possible because the common code needs too much context, or because it needs to be spread out across the function. Which brings us right to:
3. Create an internal "common" function, with an argument telling which functionality to provide. Just write the code, and put an `if` where the two functions need to do something different. That is the path the kernel took in your example.

With that said, there is another case, specific to the Linux kernel, where two functions really do seem to be almost identical. On the i386 platform, the `stat` system call is implemented not twice, but three times:

- `oldstat` syscall number 18
- `stat` syscall number 106
- `stat64` syscall number 195

The reason for that is that the Linux kernel promises complete backwards compatibility over its user space kernel interface. When a function has to be superseded for some reason, as happened to `stat` not once, but *twice* (three times if you count `fstatat`), the old system call entry needs to be kept around and remain operational.

If you look at the actual implementation, however, you will notice that there is very little difference between them, and they all end up calling, pretty much, the same function.